# How to develop pick avilable slot button in this design using flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

in this design how to do the available slot picker section using flutter please answer this and help me

[image]

Comment: There are many ways of doing it. Can you include what you;ve tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ActionChip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ActionChip-class.html)/ container with decoration... with [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) or GridView or Row and column widget,

You can play with this widget and decoration

```dart
class G extends StatefulWidget {
  const G({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<G> createState() => _GState();
}

class _GState extends State<G> {
  String? selectedSlot;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: [
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          runSpacing: 8,
          spacing: 8,
          children: List.generate(
              13,
              (index) => ActionChip(
                    backgroundColor:
                        selectedSlot == "slot $index" ? Colors.green : null,
                    label: Text("slot $index"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedSlot = "slot $index";
                      });
                    },
                  )),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]